# How do I stop all of my projects redirecting to a specific URL?

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to learn Django to build a personal website where I can host some machine learning stuff I've made for others to use. In the process, I found [this tutorial by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/skeleton_website). I think what created the issue was the part saying RedirectView.as_view(url='catalog/', permanent=True). I was trying to make a simple function grapher for my site, so I used 'grapher/' instead of 'catalog/'. Now, that worked for what I was trying to do. Then I created a new django project to try some things from a different tutorial, and now when I try to run "py manage.py runserver" and go to http://localhost:8000, I still get redirected to http://localhost:8000/grapher/. This happens in all of my django projects, new and old.

Now, the really mysterious part to me was that when I tried deleting those projects AND the virtual environments I was using, then making a new virtual environment and project, I still get redirected http://localhost:8000/grapher/. I have also tried adding "path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='', permanent=True))," to my project.urls.py  file which did not work. If there are some commands I can run to give more information, I would love to. I just don't know what other detail I can post since I deleted the projects. I just want to know how to change this redirecting behavior, and a bonus would be understanding better how the issue arose.

If RedirectView.as_view() isn't the issue, previously I had been working with static files changing STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS, and using collectstaticfiles.

Comment: That is due to the `permanent=True`, it means the *browser* has *cached* this.

Comment: Ah, so clearing the cache would fix it? Edit: It sure did.

Comment: at least in Firefox that is indeed the case (https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox) strictly speaking a browser can have other caching mechanisms, although I'm not an expert in how the different browsers handles this. A 301 response means that the browser can cache the redirect (since the `permanent=True` indicates that it will *always* redirect). So a lot of browsers will make "shortcuts", and no longer bother to first hit the first view, after all that is allowed).

Answer (score 2):

Answer per Willem Van Onsem: permanent=True causes the browser to cache the redirect. Clearing the cache fixes it.